# python gettattr(function, __doc__) + file parsing

Tags: python, docstring, getattr

I need your help on **gettattr(function, __doc__)**
this works if you use it within the file of the definition
BUT

I want to find all functions withing a given file and then run **gettattr(function, __doc__)** for all the returned functions to get associated doc strings

to list all my function within the module I use :

```
import module
functionsList = [o for o in getmembers(module) if isfunction(o[1])]
```

function[0] is a string and function[1] is the memory allocation ? 
if I want to use the function as a string i need to do:

```
for function in functionList:   
    exec ("docStrings = "+function[0]+".__doc__") 
    print docStrings
```

then I would have this error:

**Error: NameError: file  line 1: name 'anotherTestFunction' is not defined**

and I tried to directly use the function

```
for function in functionList: 
    docStrings = gettattr(function[1], __doc__)
    print docStrings
```

This time I have no error but it returns : None ...

I might be missing something ... Do you have any idea ?

Cheers

Comment: Does it definitely have a docstring? (BTW you might have more luck using the `inspect` module)

Comment: Yes it does have a docstring.  So I have tried dostring = inspect.getdoc(object) with function[1] as object and I have the same result ...

Comment: Show the body of the source code for the object `function[1]` refers to

Comment: you want to see what function[1] returns ? <function anotherTestFunction at 0x13067488>

Comment: No, I want to see its source code in the file you're trying to parse. `def anotherTestFunction(): ...` etc.

Comment: def anotherTestFunction():

    """
    @usage no usage 
    
    """

    pass

Comment: I know that function[1] is the correct type of data because when I use the inspect.getargspec() it works ...

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. I have tried all kinds of ways of getting function objects, using `inspect` and otherwise, and consistently `func.__doc__` either has the docstring, when present, or `None` otherwise, just as I would expect.

Comment: okay, i got it working with inspect but not getattr... I don t know what I missed when previously tried func.__doc__

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice this before... There is a typo in your code. Are you doing `getattr(func, __doc__)` or `getattr(func, '__doc__')`. The second argument to `getattr` must resolve to a **string**.

Comment: omg ! this explains a lot ! I haven t seen either... It s now working ...

Answer (score 0):

So finally... This was a stupid mistake...
I forgot the " " around _ _doc__ ... 
It solves everything. But here is an other way of doing it in case. Use **inspect**

```
import module
functionsList = [o for o in getmembers(module) if isfunction(o[1])]

docString = functionsList.__doc__
```

this is working !